# Try and catch exceptions in Python for opening and uploading a PDF file

Tags: python, parse-platform, try-catch, python-requests

I have developed a Python module to upload a PDF file to my Parse.com project. I used "requests" for communicating with the https Parse.com server. The codes were trying to cover all possible exceptions that might be encountered while communicating with Parse as I have a corporate firewall.

```
import env
import json
import requests

def uploadFile(fileFullPath):
    result = False

    print "Attempting to upload file: " + fileFullPath

    headers = {"X-Parse-Application-Id": env.X_Parse_Application_Id,
            "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": env.X_Parse_REST_API_Key,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"}
    try:
        f = open(fileFullPath, 'r')
        files = {'file': f}
        r = requests.post(env.PARSE_HOSTNAME + env.PARSE_FILES_ENDPOINT + "/" + env.PARSE_UPLOADED_FILE_NAME, files=files, headers=headers)
        jsonResult = r.json()

        if 'error' in jsonResult:
            print "An error occurred while trying to upload the file to Parse.com. Details: " + (jsonResult["error"])
        else:
            print jsonResult["name"]
            print jsonResult["url"]

        print "Completed uploading the file."
        result = True

    # Unable to open the file
    except IOError as ex:
        print 'IOError thrown. Details: ' + ' %s' % ex
        # If file cannot be opened, IOError is thrown as well, so exit the function to avoid calling "f.close()" in "finally"

    # In the event of a network problem (e.g. DNS failure, refused connection, etc)
    except ConnectionError as ex:
        print 'ConnectionError thrown. Details: ' + ' %s' % ex

    # In the event of an invalid HTTP response
    except HTTPError as ex:
        print 'HTTPError thrown. Details: ' + ' %s' % ex

    # If time-out occurs
    except Timeout as ex:
        print 'Timeout exception thrown. Details: ' + ' %s' % ex

    # If a request exceeds the configured number of maximum redirections
    except TooManyRedirects as ex:
        print 'TooManyRedirects exception thrown. Details: ' + ' %s' % ex

    # All other exceptions
    except Exception as ex:
        print 'Unexpected error. Details:' + ' %s' % ex
    else:
        f.close()
    finally:
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myFilePath = r'D:/myfile.pdf'
    print uploadFile(myFilePath)
```

My question is if the order of those exceptions placed is correct. Is IOError always superseding any other errors?

Comment: No matter what your order of exceptions is, the type of exception raised will be caught by the concerned exception block only.

Comment: @BarunSharma No, they are checked in the order given. OP should not catch `IOError` before `ConnectionError`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, IOError isn't in the ConnectionError chain... but the general rule applies.

Comment: BTW, you should end the `except Exception` clause with a `raise` so that the error is not swallowed up. That masks a lot of errors that then become hard to debug.

Comment: @tdelaney. But I'd also need to check if the file has been correctly opened. So IOError should be caught at the first place?

Comment: IOError should be caught but only after any error that inherits from it. I didn't go through all of the errors to see what inherits where but that is the general rule. Python searches in order for the first exception with the raised exception in its inheritance chain.